# Vuex Store Automatically Updated

Tags: vue.js, store, vuejs2, vue-router, vuex

My `Vuex` store gets `automatically updated`  without calling any `getters` or `committing` any `mutation` on immediate `router change`.

I am not committing changes to VUEX until the form is saved, so it means the data is bound two way to VUEX. I was under the impression this was not possible. In this case it is not desired since if the user changes some data, then navigates away without actually clicking "save", the data is VUEX is still changed

Comment: It is possible if any of your component's references and manipulates the vuex state object directly. But you should be getting warnings in that case...

Comment: post some code please...

Comment: I would create a seperate `data` object in your component and only on 'submit' commit the changes to the store.

Comment: I am doing the same  @AfikDeri. I am using computed getters from vuex. Will it case the issue?

Comment: computed getter is bounded to the vuex state object so you need to have another variable seperated from it holding the value and only once you commit it to the store it will update the state, don't use the same one.

Comment: I'm agree with @AfikDeri. You can use strict mode and you should get warnings : https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/strict.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<template>
  <h1>{{userName}}</h1>
  <input type="text" v-model="name.selected" :placeholder="user.username" @keyup.enter="Confirm"/>
</template>

<script>
  import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
  import { updateUserData } from 'mesh-shared/api/'
  export default {
    name: 'PreferenceProfile',
    data() {
      return {
        name: {
          isActive: false,
          selected: '',
          onChange: false
        }
      }
    },
    computed: {
      ...mapGetters([
        'user',
        'preference'
      ]),
      userName() {
        if (this.name.selected !== '') {
          return this.name.selected
        } else {
          return this.user.username
        }
      }
    },
    methods: {
      toggleNameRider() {
        this.name.isActive = true
      },
      async Confirm() {
        const params = {
          userId: this.user.userId,
          accessToken: this.user.auth.accessToken,
          avatar: (this.avatar.uploadData.url) ? this.avatar.uploadData.url : this.user.avatar,
          username: this.userName
        }
        const data = await updateUserData(params)
        console.log(data)
        const user = Object.assign(this.user, {
          completed: true
        }, data.data.user)
        this.cancel()
      },
      cancel() {
        this.avatar.newUrl = ''
        this.name.selected = ''
        this.name.isActive = false
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

I recommend you to do something like this. as I understand from your question you're setting `v-model` to getter.
instead of doing that check the example below. I hope it can help.